# Information transmitting rate of a noisy discrete channel with Omission/Adding errors

Tags: probability, signal-processing, information-theory, noise

So for a discrete channel, we have a source which sends signal $i$ at probability $p(i)$ that $\sum p(i) = 1$, and the signal is transmitted through a noisy channel. In Shannon's original paper, the probability of character $i$ is received as $j$ is $p(i,j)$ because of noise.

Thus the transmitting rate of the channel could be calculated as 
$$ R = H(X) - H_Y(X)$$
$$ = -\sum_i p(i)log_2p(i) + \sum_{i,j} p(i,j)log_2p_j(i)$$

However, what if the noise could randomly **omit** the signal (sender sends signal $i$, receiver receives nothing) or **add** the signal (sender sends nothing but receiver receives signal $j$), instead of only changing signal $i$ to $j$?

How to calculate the transmitting rate then?

-- **update** --

OK, so to be more specific, the receiver doesn't know the signal is omitted or added by the noise. If the sender sends "abc" and receiver receives "bc", the receiver doesn't know there's "a" omitted.

Comment: The cases you are asking about are treated exactly the same, with the difference that you will be considering an augmented alphabet for transmitter and/or receiver symbols, with the addition of the "nothing" symbol. You should redefine the symbol and channel probabilities for this case and then calculate rate using the standard formula.

Comment: @Stelios That's an answer

Comment: @Paul Wrote a more elaborate version of my comment as an answer. Thanks for the motivation! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your original problem (channel) consisted of the transmitter sending symbols from the finite alphabet $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{I}$ and the receiver observing symbols from the finite alphabet $\{Y_j\}_{i=1}^{J}$. Then, as you state, you can obtain the maximum rate by computing the mutual information for given joint input-output probabilities  $p(i,j)\triangleq \mathbb{P}(\text{transmit } X_i, \text{receive } Y_j), i =1,\ldots I, j=1,
\ldots J$.

Now, what you are doing by introducing the options of "omitting the signal" and/or "adding the signal" is essentially considering the augmented symbol alphabets $\{\tilde{X}_i\}_{i=1}^{I+1} \triangleq \{X_i\}_{i=1}^{I} \cup \{0\}$ and $\{\tilde{Y}_j\}_{j=1}^{J+1} \triangleq  \{Y_j\}_{i=1}^{J} \cup \{0\}$, for the transmitter and receiver, respectively. This new setup/channel is, of course, also characterized by a set of joint probabilities $\mathbb{P}(\text{transmit } \tilde{X}_i, \text{receive }  \tilde{Y}_j)$. Note that these probabilities should be, in general, different from the transition probabilities of the original channel, even for the pairs of non-zero transmit-receive symbols.

You can now repeat the exercise of computing the rate as you did for the original channel, this time considering the joint probabilities for the augmented alphabets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm also thinking of using something like a 0 or a null character to represent the errors. However, if we use a 0, the source rate for $X$ will be different considering the different probability of making **omit/add** errors, which means, the information rate of $X$ is dependent on the channel and the noise?

Comment: Also, could you please tell me how the term is wrong?

Comment: @DrustZ Of course, if you introduce a $0$ ("null") symbol in your alphabets, you need to figure out the new joint probabilities (which, typically, will depend on the physical channel and noise properties). Apologies for my comment on your formula (now removed); I did not notice the subscript in the notation (I was expecting the notation $p(i|j)$ instead).

Comment: Got it! However, that is not directly intuitive: the source information is actually fixed, right? because there's actually no "0" in the alphabets... And when it's transmitted, the information source should also be fixed

Comment: @DrustZ When you are "omitting" the signal generated by a given source (with some probability), you are basically generating a *new* source (with an augmented alphabet). Note that the "null" symbol of the new source is a perfectly valid symbol that can "carry" information. Of course, the symbol distribution of the new source will depend on the original source, but will be different, depending on how/when you decide to omit a symbol.

Comment: Hi, I find a strange thing here: what if there's only omission error? Then $log p_y(x)$ will not be affected by the "0" symbol. For example, if the channel either perfectly transmits the symbol or discards it, the transmission rate will be the same as there's no emission error, because $p_y (x)$ will always be 1, so the calculation of $H(Y|X)$ is 0.

Comment: @DrustZ What you are saying is not correct. $p(x|y=0)=p(x)$, that is, the receiver may not observe anything, but does know how the input symbols are distributed.

Comment: Yes, but here's what I'm saying: $p(x|y=i) = 1$ because the channel either perfectly transmits or discards. Sure, $p(x|y=0) = p(x)$, However, how do we know there's something that's discarded if we only have Y? I mean, 0 symbol doesn't occupy positions, so we don't know if there's a 0 or not in Y, which is the essential difference between 0 and other symbols.

Comment: could this be a compound channel? which means there's essentially three channels, one is only making normal error (i to j), one is making **omission error**, one is making **adding error**. And each channel has a possibility.

Comment: Nevermind I conducted a math prove, they're equal in the transmission rate (compound channel method and null character method, at least in the case there's only omission error), Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: @DrustZ There is a subtle point here. In all my answers I assume that "omit" event means that the receiver does not observe anything but *knows* that something was sent. By your comment, it seems that you are considering the case where the receiver in the omit event is also not aware that something was indeed sent. The latter case is completely different and probably difficult to characterize (I am not aware of an information theoretic formulation for this channel)

Comment: Oh, actually I'm asking for the latter case... you don't know there's an omission or adding error.

Comment: And I think the solution might also be applicable for the latter case? Because even the receiver isn't aware, the probability of omission/adding error could be calculated.